# How to select a the GPU with Direct2D's D2D1CreateFactory()?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, direct2d

My laptop has NVIDIA Optimus (so there's an Intel GPU).

However, I want to use the NVIDIA card for Direct2D to see if I can get better performance.
(I don't want to modify the NVIDIA settings, I want to select the adapter within the program itself.)

How can I do this though?

There is no option I can find in `D2D1CreateFactory` that allows me to select the device or adapter... it always seems to select the default GPU. How do I obtain a `ID2D1Factory` for a non-default GPU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `D3D10CreateDevice` and then interoperability between `D2D` and `D3D`.

- [Surface Sharing Between Windows Graphics APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee913554.aspx)
- [Direct2D and Direct3D Interoperability Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370966.aspx)

`Direct3D` allows you to get picky with the device, `D2D` not... AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks, it was a ***lot*** more painful than I expected. For anyone else planning to try this -- it doesn't seem to benefit performance a single bit going from Intel HD Graphics 4600 to NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M.

Comment: @Mehrdad Np. Framerate might be internally capped to vsync. Plus, you really need to push D2D to see a difference between the two, I think... And time the draw speed with `QueryPerformanceCounter()`, nothing else. *PS: Heard Intel 4600 is quite good!*

Comment: It seems the bottleneck is Direct2D's code itself (the CWidener class, according to my stack traces), not the hardware. I only get 20-30% GPU usage (I'm drawing thousands of lines on the screen, basically).